# C call tensorflow: makefile fail to execute a.out

Tags: c, tensorflow

I am new to TensorFlow. At the moment, I am learning TensorFlow for C code on my Macbook. I follow the instructions by Google and manage to run the 'hello world' in C.

I set the paths on my bash_profile as follows:

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/tensorflow/lib

export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/tensorflow/lib.
```

Here is my makefile.

```
tensorlib = -L/usr/local/tensorflow-1.15.0/lib/

tensorlnk = -I/usr/local/tensorflow-1.15.0/include/

task:

    mpicc -c hello.c $(tensorlnk)

    mpicc hello.o $(tensorlib)

run:

    mpirun -np 4 ./a.out
```

I can compile the program and generate the executable, `a.out`. In my terminal, I can run the program directly using `mpirun -np 4 ./a.out`. But when I try to execute a.out using the command `make run` of my makefile, I get the error message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libtensorflow.1.dylib 
Referenced from: /Users/usr/Documents/code/dev/TensorFlow/c/./a.out
Reason: image not found
```

Could anyone tell me how to fix it?

Many thanks in advance.